# Why doesn't grep give me the all found strings?

Tags: bash

I have txt file whose inside there are 8 times "ATOMIC_POSITIONS" string and when I'm trying to write each one of them with ;

```
AtomicPos=$(grep -n "ATOMIC_POSITIONS" hw1_out_si_wire.txt)
echo $AtomicPos
```

İt gives me just the last one

```
4779:ATOMIC_POSITIONS (bohr)
```

4779 is the line number , where is the last one.In fact , after that I was going to take the last one so that I can take the next lines after the last "ATOMIC_POSITIONS", but, hence, it gives me directly the last one ,so I continued like ;

```
$NtL=262
i=1
until [ $i == $NtL ]
do
Pos=$(grep -A $i ATOMIC_POSITIONS  hw1_out_si_wire.txt)
echo $Pos
i=$(expr $i + 1)
unset Pos
done
```

But when I run that , it starts from the first "ATOMIC_POSITIONS" and continues.

Could someone explain why is that ?

Comment: and convert the text file from dos format (CRLF) to unix format (LF) line-endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read grep output into an array you have to change

```
AtomicPos=$(grep -n "ATOMIC_POSITIONS" hw1_out_si_wire.txt)
```

to

```
AtomicPos=( $(grep -n "ATOMIC_POSITIONS" hw1_out_si_wire.txt) )
```

This way you will have all the matched patterns in `AtomicPos` then loop over the array and print each element.